# Как разделить натуральное число на цифры в C# не используя массивы чистой математикой

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика

Я получил задание: Дано натуральное число. Определить его максимальную и минимальную цифру.
и я написал код:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите натуральное число: ");
        string x = Console.ReadLine();
        string [] j  = x.Split();
        int min = int.Parse(j[0]);
        int max = int.Parse(j[0]);
        for(int i = 0; i < j.Length; i++)
        {
            if(max < int.Parse(j[i]))
            {
                max = int.Parse(j[i]);
            }
            if (min > int.Parse(j[i]))
            {
                min = int.Parse(j[i]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"максимальная цифра {max}, минимальная цифра {min}");
    }
```

но оказалось что нельзя использовать массивы. Препод сказал написать что то с делением с помощью математики. Типо 2038 деление без остатка на 1000 дает нам первое число 2 и так далее. Но я понятия не имею какова должна быть логика чтобы при числе любой длинны такая тема работала. Помогите подскажите алгоритм или типо того а то в голове нет идей

Comment: Так возьмите остаток от деления на 10, потом разделите на 10. Повторяйте, пока число не обнулится

Comment: Блин по идее так просто, но я не додумался спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Вот так...

```
Console.Write("Введите натуральное число: ");
int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int min = 10;
int max = -1;
do 
{
    int d = x % 10;
    if (max < d) max = d;
    if (min > d) min = d;
    x /= 10;
} while(x != 0);
Console.WriteLine($"максимальная цифра {max}, минимальная цифра {min}");
```

Comment: @MBo Логично, спасибо!

Comment: Допустимо 9 и 0 вместо 10 и -1. Пока отвлекался при написании ответа, опоздал :)

Comment: @aepot В принципе да. Так же, как и 11 и -2 :)

Comment: Ага, но не совсем одно и то же, 9 и 0 в некоторых случаях дадут меньшее количество присваиваний на 1. ;)